# combobox select first item on form load event.how i can change that it not select first item on form load

Tags: vb.net

i load combobox on form load event in vb.net.it load id correctly and select first item(id) on load event in combobox.i want that it not select first item on load event.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim dset As New DataSet
    Dim dpt As New SqlDataAdapter

    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    con.ConnectionString = "data source=abc;initial catalog=LoginDB;integrated security=true"
    cmd.Connection = con
    con.Open()

    cmd.CommandText = "show_id"
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    dpt.SelectCommand = cmd
    dpt.Fill(dset, "tab")
    ComboBox1.DataSource = dset.Tables("tab")
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "id"

End Sub
```

i want combobox load "id" and not select the first item("id") on load event.but it load "id" correctly and select first item("id") on load event.

Comment: If you only care about user selections, subscribe to the [`SelectionChangeCommitted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted) event instead of the `SelectedIndexChange` event. The former is triggered only when a user selects an item.

Comment: thank you...you understand my problem and this works well..

Comment: this does send the correct text of combobox when user change the item of combobox?? means does not send the correct text of combobox.text??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert the following code after assigning the DataSource. It resets the selection.

```
 ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1
```

Comment: this not display first item in combobox but it search on the basis of first item of combobox??

Comment: @UbaidUllah the code only sets the SelectedIndex to `-1` which means "not selected" (`0` would mean first item on the other hand).

Comment: i search "name" on the basis of combobox.combobox load correctly on form load event but it select first item on form load event and also search on the basis of first item.how i can stop this selection on form load event ???

i use combobox1.selectedindex=-1. this show no item in combobox but search on the basis of first item of combobox...